# yii2: how to use multi rules for access in behaviors

Tags: yii2

i want to add new rules in behaviors

How can I do this?

this is my sample of this issue :

```
    public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                    [
                    'actions' => ['create', 'index', 'clearing', 'transfer', 'response'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
                    [
                    'actions' => ['virtual'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['*'],
                ]
            ],
            'denyCallback' => function ($rule, $action)
                {


                if (\Yii::$app->user->can('@'))
                    {

                    } else
                    {

                    return $action->controller->redirect(Url::to(['user/login']));
                    }
                },
        ],
    ];
}
```

why guest users redirecting to user login  is virtual action?!

Comment: rules only one and inside rules you can define many rules using array.

Comment: question is updated!

Comment: @Saltern did you find a solution?

Comment: no I did not find

Answer (score 0):

You can add new array to define new rule

```
'access' => [
      'class' => AccessControl::className(),
      'rules' => [
          [
            'actions' => ['login', 'register', 'error'],
            'allow' => true,
          ],
          [
            // 'actions' => ['logout', 'index'],
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['@'],
          ],
      ],
    ],
  ];
```